# Is it true that $\Big[(ak + \frac{b}{2})\cos(\frac{t}{2})\Big] + \Big[(bk - \frac{a}{2})\sin(\frac{t}{2})\Big] = k\cos(\frac{t}{2})$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is it true that
$$
\left[\left(ak + \frac{b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right] + \left[\left(bk - \frac{a}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right] = k\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)
$$
If yes, how to prove it?
Is there a hidden trigonometric identity behind it?

Question taken [MIT 18.03 (end of problem 1 page 2)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/solution-by-integrating-factors/MIT18_03SCF11_rec_04s5_sol.pdf)

Comment: there's a parenthesis missing

Comment: thanks for the comment @math. I corrected the question

Comment: Bracket still missing.

Comment: @Tavish: is it better now?

Comment: @ecjb Understandable now.

Comment: @YouKnowMe: I corrected it

Answer (score 1):

That equation is true iff $$\left( k(a-1) +\frac b2 \right) \cos (t/2) = \left(\frac a2 -bk\right) \sin(t/2) \\ \iff \tan(t/2) = \frac{k(a-1) +\frac b2}{\frac a2 -bk} $$ The RHS is just a constant. If this were to hold true for all $t$, then that would imply that $\tan x$ is a constant function.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Tavish. How to interpret then the answer of the course?

Comment: @ecjb $a,b,k$ in that problem are probably related somehow, to make that equation true in context of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's trivially false for $k=0$ and $a,b\neq 0$, and there's no reason why it would be true for other values. For instance for $t=0$, it gives $ak+b/2 = k$.

But **in your exercise**, you know that $(ak + \frac{b}{2})\cos(\frac{t}{2}) + (bk - \frac{a}{2})\sin \frac{t}{2} = k\cos \frac{t}{2}$, and the point is to find a relation between $a,b,k$ such that this is true.

Since $(t\mapsto \cos \frac{t}{2}, t\mapsto \sin \frac{t}{2})$ is linearly indepedent, you get that :

$ak+b/2 = k$ and $bk-a/2 = 0$.

Comment: @thanks for your answer: I actually put the source in the question. How can you explain the equation with the given source?